# Tools or techniques for showing html code

Tags: html, web

For my internship i need to develop a WYSIWYG editor that wil support some logic. This wil be if-statements and loops. I know that there are WYSIWYG editors on the market. But all off them don't have the support for implent that kind of logic.

What i'm looking for is some techniques or tools that can provide showing html code. With preference syntax support with color highlighting.

I'm aweare of Codemirror and the monaca editor already.

If somebody knows more of that kind of tools, or maybe some technieques that can help to realize something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any devtools that have WYSIWYG capabilities. The closest thing is probably using codepen.io or jsfiddle.net

Comment: Asking for tools or other offsite resources is prohibited on SO and there's a specific close reason for these types of questions. Instead of posting an answer, you should vote to close the question as off-topic.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't make the rules around here